# Basic information on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I am trying to build an application with devise and where there will be more than one role.

Such has user/admin. If i understand properly the documentation the way devise works and you build a new model/controller called user for one role and a new model/controller for admin. Which his fairly simple however here the issue i have

route.rb I have the following

```
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :customers
  resources :events
  root :to => 'events#index'
```

In the controller I however place this

```
  before_filter :authenticate_customer!
```

I also try has follow

```
  before_filter :authenticate_customer! || :authenticate_admin!
```

But both technics still redirect me to the sign in page if I login has an admin. What should I do both to talk, unless i create two different website which then turn out to be useless.

Here are also a few more questions. When i go into edit it ask me for current_password, how can i remove this feature?

Is there also a way for me to stop member or registering ( aka admin)

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making an app right now that also has multiple roles (admin, student, teacher, etc). You need to realize that Devise is an **authentication** solution, it authenticates that a user is real. For role-based permissions, you need an **authorization** solution, which authorizes a user to do some action. Devise has support for an admin role, but for more than that, you'll want an authorization solution.

[Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/) is the gem I'd suggest for that. I used [this tutorial](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/) when I was setting it up for my app. There's also a [part 2 to the tutorial](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/09/29/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2-restful-resources-for-administrators/) that you might find interesting. It not too hard to setup either (I'm just learning Rails myself since about 8 months ago).